# Cascading dynamically added fields in Symfony6

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony6

I have a form with (in the end) 3 Dropdown selections:

`FieldA` `FieldB` `FieldC`

with Options of FieldB dependent on the selection for fieldA and Options of FieldC dependent on the selection for fieldB

The Relations are:

```
EntityB ManyToMany EntityA

EntityC ManyToOne EntityB
```

Everything is working fine, execpt that on Submit the form is not valid with the Error being "This form should not contain extra fields" and the culprit being fieldC

what am I doing wrong?

here's my code for the FormType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fieldA', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => EntityA::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityARepository $a) {
                    return $a->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])

        ;

        $builder->get('fieldA')->addEventListener(
          FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
          function(FormEvent $event) {
              $form = $event->getForm();
              $this->setupFieldB(
                  $form->getParent(),
                  $form->getData()
              );
          }
        );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if (!$data or !isset($data['fieldA'])) {
                    return;
                }
                $this->setupFieldB(
                    $event->getForm(),
                    $data['fieldA']
                );
            }
        );

        if ($builder->has('fieldB')) {
            $builder->get('fieldB')->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
                function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $this->setupFieldC(
                        $form->getParent(),
                        $form->getData()
                    );
                }
            );
        }

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if (!$data or !isset($data['fieldB'])) {
                    return;
                }
                $this->setupFieldC(
                    $event->getForm(),
                    $data['fieldB']
                );
            }
        );
    }

    private function setupFieldB(FormInterface $form, ?string $selectedfieldA)
    {
        if (is_null($selectedfieldA)) {
            $form->remove('fieldB');
            $form->remove('fieldC');
            return;
        } else {
            $fieldA = $this->EntityARepository->findOneBy(['name' => $selectedfieldA]);
            $form
                ->add('fieldB', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => EntityB::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityBRepository $b) use ($fieldA) {
                        return $b->createQueryBuilder('b')
                            ->andWhere(':fieldA MEMBER of b.fieldAs')
                            ->setParameter('fieldA', $fieldA)
                            ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                ]);
        }
    }

    private function setupFieldC(FormInterface $form, ?string $selectedFieldB)
    {
        if (is_null($selectedFieldB)) {
            $form->remove('fieldC');
            return;
        } else {
            $fieldB = $this->fieldBRepository->findOneBy(['name' => $selectedFieldB]);
            $form
                ->add('fieldC', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => EntityC::class,
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityCRepository $c) use ($fieldB) {
                        return $c->getQueryBuilderWithFilter(['fieldB' => $fieldB]);
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

after some more research I found the following solution:

a) remove the part with `if ($builder->has('fieldB')) {` - as this always resolved to false anyway.

b) rewrite the function setupFieldB ... as follows:

```
private function setupFieldB(FormInterface $form, ?string $selectedfieldA)
{
    if (is_null($selectedfieldA)) {
        $form->remove('fieldB');
        $form->remove('fieldC');
        return;
    } else {
        $fieldA = $this->EntityARepository->findOneBy(['name' => $selectedfieldA]);
        
        $newBuilder = $form->getConfig()->getFormFactory()->createNamedBuilder('fieldB', 
            EntityType::class, null, [
                'class' => EntityB::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityBRepository $b) use ($fieldA) {
                    return $b->createQueryBuilder('b')
                        ->andWhere(':fieldA MEMBER of b.fieldAs')
                        ->setParameter('fieldA', $fieldA)
                        ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ]);
        
        // now we can add the listener:
        $newBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $this->setupFieldC(
                $form->getParent(),
                $form->getData()
            );
        });
        
        // finally add the field to the form
        $form->add($newBuilder->getForm());
    }
}
```